# Questions and considerations to ask client for designing a database

Tags: database, database-design, mysql, database-security

so as title says, I would like to hear your advices what are the most important questions to consider and ask  end-users before **designing database** for their application. We are to make database-oriented app, with special attenion to pay on **db security** (access control, encryption, integrity, backups)... Database will also keep some personal information about people, which is considered sensitive by law regulations, so security must be good.

I worked on school projects with databases, but this is first time working "in real world", where this db security has real implications.

So I found some advices and questions to ask on internet, but here I always get best ones. All help appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some other specifics besides what has already been said:

- Do you have any Regulatory
  requirements for data access and
  storage (Sarbanes-Oxley and HIPAA
  come to mind)
- Do you need to be able to audit
  record changes
- What internal controls do you need
  reflected in the database
- What business rules must be followed
  under what circumstances
- How large to you expect the data to
  get - the larger the data store
  expected the more critical to design
  with performance in mind from the
  start
- How flexible do you want the system
  to be (do you want to be able to add
  columns on the fly? OR add business
  rules) Be careful with this one, make
  sure the client understands that
  flexibilty often comes at the cost of
  performance.
- Do you need a separate data warehouse
  for reporting?
- How do you need the data populated?
  Will it come from an application,
  multiple applications, data imports
  or a combination?
- What databases do you currently have
  license for? Do you want to have
  this application use it?
- Will different groups of users need
  different accesses?
- How is the process currently being
  handled, can we have access to that
  database or see the current process
  in action. Observe, for a minimum of
  one day, the client using the current
  system. Take extensive notes, you will learn many things no one will think to tell you.
- Do you need to migrate data from the
  old system

Comment: Hi! Thanx foe advices! Can you just explain me this one bit more : "What internal controls do you need reflected in the database"?
Because I thaught you mean it on different types of user access, but i see you mention that in the end of the list?

Comment: Internal controls is an accounting term. It means the controls the company has designed into the system to prevent fraud. For instance, no one should be able to inititate and approve a purchase. This prevent people from setting up a fake company and creating fake orders to that company just to collect the money without providing a needed good or service. Internal controls are critical to any system that handles money and any programmer who is not familiar with the term who handles a financial system, needs to do some in depth reading about them or the system he or she designs will be at risk.

Answer (score 3):

i would start with:

- Please explain your business to me.
- Which processes are you looking to
  automate or improve?
- Do you have any reports you need to
  generate?
- Do you need inputs to any other
  systems?

Answer (score 1):

- use cases (google for that, it does not need to be drawings, text is fine)
- inputs
- outputs
- static data
- historical data

From there you derive the info you need to store, you apply 4th NF, and go !
Good luck !  8-))